# Passing PSCredential Class as parameter in SqlServerDsc module

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dsc

I'm new to posting and new to powershell DSC and powershell in general. I'm testing the SqlServiceAccount resource in the SqlServerDsc module and can't figure out how to use the PSCredential Class. My goal is to have the credentials in the variable, but can't figure out how to do this properly. I looked at the example and read the psm1 for the resource on it's github but still lost. 
Here's the code I'm using to test it, the password as well as other info is in another script being called at the bottom of this script. The window prompting me to input credentials is popping up but I want my credentials placed in the variable to populate this.

```
Configuration SQLInstall

{param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $PackagePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    $ServiceAccountCredential

)
Import-DscResource –ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
Import-DSCResource -ModuleName ComputerManagementDsc
Import-DSCResource -ModuleName SqlServerDsc

Node $AllNodes.where{ $_.Role.Contains("SQLENGINE") }.NodeName
{

    Log ParamLog
    {
        Message = "Running SQLInstall. PackagePath = $PackagePath"
    }

# Password info here
$password = $using:Node.Service4SQLPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
$username = $using:Node.Service4SQLAccount 
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

    SqlServiceAccount SetServiceAccount_DatabaseEngine
    {
        ServerName     = $Node.NodeName
        InstanceName   = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        ServiceType    = 'DatabaseEngine'
        ServiceAccount = $ServiceAccountCredential
        RestartService = $true
        Force          = $true
        DependsOn      = "[Script]InstallSQLServer"
    }

    SqlServiceAccount SetServiceAccount_SQLServerAgent
    {
        ServerName     = $Node.NodeName
        InstanceName   = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        ServiceType    = 'SQLServerAgent'
        ServiceAccount = $ServiceAccountCredential
        RestartService = $true
        Force          = $true
        DependsOn      = "[Script]InstallSQLServer"
    }

    SqlServiceAccount SetServiceAccount_IntegrationServices
    {
        ServerName     = $Node.NodeName
        InstanceName   = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        ServiceType    = 'IntegrationServices'
        ServiceAccount = $ServiceAccountCredential
        RestartService = $true
        Force          = $true
        DependsOn      = "[Script]InstallSQLServer"
    }               
}}

SQLInstall -ConfigurationData C:\PowerShell_UserScripts\MyServerData.psd1 `
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mandatory parameter in your configuration called `$ServiceAccountCredential` which you use in your configuration.

But then somewhere in the middle you populate a variable called `$Credential`, but you don't use it anywhere. Move that out of the `Configuration` definition (it doesn't belong there), and then pass it as the parameter:

```
# Password info here
$password = $using:Node.Service4SQLPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
$username = $using:Node.Service4SQLAccount 
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

Configuration SQLInstall    
{
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $PackagePath,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    $ServiceAccountCredential

)

<# ... #>

}

SQLInstall -ConfigurationData C:\PowerShell_UserScripts\MyServerData.psd1 -ServiceAccountCredential $Credential
```

Comment: Thanks! I recieved this error message. I don't think it's fetching my variables:

ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At line:3 char:41
+ ... Node.Service4SQLPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

Comment: @JulesSQL ah I see, that's my fault for not reading closely. I see now you're taking the password from configuration data. In that case I don't know why you're using `$Using:` at all; `$Node` should be fine. But also in this case you should not have that mandatory parameter on your configuration. It should either be optional or omitted altogether, and then you would change your reference from `$ServiceAccountCredential` to `$Credential` (or conversely change your assignment on the conversion phase).

Comment: Yes! I have it working now, thank you! I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @briantist! It works now after a couple tweaks, here's the solution

```
Configuration SQLInstall                                               
{param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]
    $PackagePath
)
Import-DscResource –ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
Import-DSCResource -ModuleName ComputerManagementDsc
Import-DSCResource -ModuleName SqlServerDsc


Node $AllNodes.where{ $_.Role.Contains("SQLENGINE") }.NodeName
{

    Log ParamLog
    {
        Message = "Running SQLInstall. PackagePath = $PackagePath"
    }


    $password = $Node.Service4SQLPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
    $username = $Node.Service4SQLAccount 
    $ServiceAccountCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

    SqlServiceAccount SetServiceAccount_DatabaseEngine
    {
        ServerName     = $Node.NodeName
        InstanceName   = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        ServiceType    = 'DatabaseEngine'
        ServiceAccount = $ServiceAccountCredential
        RestartService = $true
        Force          = $true
        #DependsOn     = "[Script]InstallSQLServer"
    }

    SqlServiceAccount SetServiceAccount_SQLServerAgent
    {
        ServerName     = $Node.NodeName
        InstanceName   = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        ServiceType    = 'SQLServerAgent'
        ServiceAccount = $ServiceAccountCredential
        RestartService = $true
        Force          = $true
        #DependsOn     = "[Script]InstallSQLServer"
    }

    SqlServiceAccount SetServiceAccount_IntegrationServices
    {
        ServerName     = $Node.NodeName
        InstanceName   = 'MSSQLSERVER'
        ServiceType    = 'IntegrationServices'
        ServiceAccount = $ServiceAccountCredential
        RestartService = $true
        Force          = $true
        #DependsOn     = "[Script]InstallSQLServer"
    }


}                                                                 
}SQLInstall -ConfigurationData C:\PowerShell_UserScripts\MyServerData.psd1 -PackagePath "C:\PowerShell_UserScripts"
```